# Open a URL using chrome and specify the local ChromeUser, for testing purposes

Tags: macos, google-chrome

For testing purposes, I am attempting to automate the opening of a URL from a script.  I generally use google chrome under a special local ChromeUser solely for the purpose of testing.  Local Chrome users are outlined [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824).

I have found [this](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) which specifies the flags when opening google chrome and it's usage discussed [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags), however when I execute commands a specified I run into an error:

```
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
[0506/035142:INFO:breakpad_mac.mm(148)] Breakpad disabled
[15398:-1409084736:2001131272496316:ERROR:process_singleton_mac.cc(102)] Unable to obtain profile lock.
```

What is the issue with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lock file in the Application Support folder for Chrome.

```
rm -f Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/SingletonLock
```